# Silverman's rule of thumb - local linear regression

Tags: regression

I want to estimate the optimal bandwidth value in local linear regression, and came across Silverman's rule of thumb.

If I consider two sets of x-values, say
$x_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$,
$x_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,16)$.

Using Silverman's rule of thumb, I get a bandwidth approximately 4 times larger for $x_2$ than $x_1$.

However, if I use kernel regression to fit each of these using the bandwidths obtained from Silverman's rule of thumb (say $y = \sin(x_i) + \varepsilon$), then the data generated using $x_1$ fits much better than that using $x_2$. Have I misunderstood when this rule is supposed to be used?

Comment: Why and how would you expect that rule of thumb to apply to local linear regression?  At most a bandwidth calculated from the SD and IQR of the predictor could be used, but such a rule has nothing to do with the variability of outcome given predictor which is perhaps the main issue here.  That said, my own private default with biweight kernel as another default starts with 1/5 the range of the predictor, rounded to a nice number. I claim no more than this: that can be a fair start for the kind of data I have and the kind of smoothing I tend to want.

Comment: Some very smart statisticians have worked on this problem of choice -- and it is important for anyone who needs to look at many such graphs and doesn't have time or inclination to make separate decisions. But there could be a long riff on why optima are hard to define,  which is why there is so much conflicting advice too.

Comment: What rule of thumb, exactly, did you discover? The only one that immediately comes to mind for me would be used for density estimation, not local linear regression.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes you're right. I assumed it would also hold for kernel regression, but it would seem I was wrong to assume that!